# Need SQL idea to retrieve the count of each product in my database

Tags: sql

I have this database:

```
Product Quantity DateDelivery
Malox   2        10/10/2016
Malox   1        11/10/2016
Malox   5        11/10/2016
Panadol 3        15/10/2016
```

I need an SQL Query that can show the quantity of each product with each date
in this case, there are two "Malox" but with defferent dates, and I want 
the query give me the following result:

```
Product Quantity DateDelivery
Malox   2        10/10/2016
Malox   6        11/10/2016
```

Comment: @FreeConsulting Completely irrelevant, as far as I can tell - I've edited the question to remove Delphi, there's nothing about Delphi here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to group by product and date, ie

```
select Product, sum(Quantity), DateDelivery from tab group by Product, DateDelivery
```